# Are Swift private features (like Function builders) rejected by the App Store review process?

Tags: swift, app-store, swift5

I'm trying to build some features using function builders (@_functionBuilder included in Swift 5.1).

I know using private framework APIs is disallowed, but does the same apply for private language features?

I have tried looking this up but couldn't find any relevant information on the topic specifically addressing this. Grateful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: No, should be fine. It's only private Apple stuff that you can't use.